# Do AngularJS and and angular-ui-bootstrap have their own comment/css class directives?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The reason I'm asking this question is this: https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider

I want to disable comment and css class directives with `commentDirectivesEnabled` and `cssClassDirectivesEnabled`.

And as stated on that page:

> This should however only be used if you are sure that no class
>   directives are used in the application (including any 3rd party
>   directives).

Update: I found out that ngTransclude, ngCloak are examples of css class directives. Is there a full list of class/comment directives so I can make sure disabling those will not do any harm?

Comment: It seems to me that it disables the comment/class directives for the whole application as in the link you provided it is stated: _Calling this function with false disables the compilation of directives on element classes for the **whole** application_

Comment: I know what it does. Documentation states it clearly.